# Regarding Poisson and Dirac brackets

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, constrained-dynamics, poisson-brackets

The question starts with why Poisson brackets (in constrained systems) gives different relation if we substitute the constraints before or after expanding the bracket, and why this difference in relations cause a problem. More clearly speaking why do we care that "if we substitute constraints before expanding the bracket the relations don't match with the fundamental Poisson bracket relations", what is the problem in moving on with these new relations that we got (I know it gives wrong answer, I want to know the reason it is giving wrong) and continuing the problem.

this question was mentioned possibly duplicate by QMechanic, and gave a link to another answer ,where the validity of the use of Poisson brackets is refuted in terms of quantization, I just want to know that mathematically what in the definition of PB makes it useless when we have constraints. Lets say we are in an $2N$ dim space and we have one constraint say $q^N=0$ and this will give rise to a secondary constraint on $p^N$, Now if I don't want to exclude the $p^N and\ q^N$ what renders the definition of PB useless in this new space ( I know ${[q^N,p^N]}\neq $  1 , I am asking why it need to be 1 to continue using the PB), Also they say DB are the projection of PB into the constrained space , why we need a projection while we are still operating in the 2N dim space. I kindly request an answer about problems in the model rather than the problems arising due to quantization

Comment: Perhaps looking at the virtually trivial circle, sphere, or [hypersphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket#Further_Illustration_for_a_hypersphere) would make it apparent.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165865/2451 and links therein.

Comment: If you eliminated $q^N$ in the Lagrangian, it could not define a $p^N$ in the Hamiltonian, so a corresponding PB, no? Can you clarify what it is you are doing? Looks like a trivial homework problem; is it?

Comment: What i am saying is that I don't want to eliminate the variables which are constrained, They are still in the phase space. So now what is wrong with the PB I mentioned above not being 1? why do we care it is not 1?

Comment: Do you appreciate Dirac introduced DBs as a preamble to quantization? Have you worked out the quantization on a circle?

Comment: can we avoid any reasoning that arises from motivating quantization and look only at the classical picture